# Background ScheduledAgent Out of memory exception when setting Bitmap Image Source from stream

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I wanted to update Flip Tile Back Image periodically so that I added `ScheduledAgent` Project and tried to save image in a fixed path inside `isolated Share Folder`. But am getting out of memory exception when I setting `BitmapImage` Source from `Image Stream` .

Here is the code

```
    using (var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        const string filePath = @"Shared\ShellContent\FlipBackImage.jpg";
        var filename = "Image.png";
        var stream = !isoFile.FileExists(filename) ? null : isoFile.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        if (stream != null)
        {
            if (isoFile.FileExists(filePath))
            {
                isoFile.DeleteFile(filePath);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("currentMemory"+DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage);
            var bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
            bi.SetSource(stream); //out of memory exception getting here
            var wbm=new WriteableBitmap(bi);
            using (var streamFront = isoFile.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                wbm.SaveJpeg(streamFront, 691, 336, 0, 80);
            }
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Utils.DisposeImage(wbm));
        }
```

Am getting the exception each time when try to set an `Image` of `Resolution 1500x1100` even it's size is just `29 kb`. 
How to handle this?

Comment: The picture is 29kb in compressed format. When loaded in a `BitmapImage` it needs to be decoded, and will use 4 bytes per pixel (one byte per color, plus the alpha channel). That makes 1500 x 1100 x 4 = 6600000 bytes = about 6.5 MB. A background agent can use only 10MB of RAM, so just the picture is using 65% of the available memory. Add the memory required to load your application, and you have it.

Comment: On WP8, you can use the `DecodePixelWidth` and `DecodePixelHeight` properties of the `BitmapImage` to avoid decoding the whole picture in memory (since you'll resize it anyway): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelheight.aspx  Unfortunately, as far as I know you can't set those properties on WP7

Comment: @KooKiz thanks for the answer.  But for a 3MB sized image still problem exists.

Comment: I have an identical issue:(

Comment: Basically, you cannot load bitmap image larger than 1280x768 in background agent because it will throw OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 0):

iso.Close();

write this once the image stream read completed